# Python3 でリスト内のリストの要素を一つだけ書き換えたい

Tags: python, python3

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

というリストを作りたかったのですが、

```
>>> def makeboard():
    _ = [0 for i in range(5)]
    board = [_ for i in range(5)]
    return board
>>> board = makeboard()
>>> board
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> board[2][2] = 1
>>> board
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

のようになってしまいました。シャローコピーであるためかと思い、

```
>>> import copy
>>> board = copy.deepcopy(makeboard())
>>> board[2][2] = 1
```

というふうに試してみても

```
>>> board
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

と何も変わらず。どのようにすればよいでしょうか？理由も併せてお願いします。

Comment: この記事が参考になるでしょう。[Pythonのリスト（配列）を任意の値・要素数で初期化](https://note.nkmk.me/python-list-initialize/)

Answer (score 3):

[id(object)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#id) を使用して `board`変数(リスト型)の中身を調べてみます。

**id(object)**

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
> 　CPython implementation detail: **This is the address of the object in memory.**

```py
>>> def makeboard():
      _ = [0 for i in range(5)]
      board = [_ for i in range(5)]
      return board
>>> board = makeboard()
>>> for i, b in enumerate(board):
      print(f'board[{i}] = {hex(id(b))}')

board[0] = 0x7f81d81bc840
board[1] = 0x7f81d81bc840
board[2] = 0x7f81d81bc840
board[3] = 0x7f81d81bc840
board[4] = 0x7f81d81bc840
```

instance id(memory address)が全て同じである事が判ります。次に、質問にある様に `copy.deepcopy()` を実行してみます。

```py
>>> import copy
>>> board = copy.deepcopy(makeboard())
>>> for i, b in enumerate(board):
      print(f'board[{i}] = {hex(id(b))}')

board[0] = 0x7f98c8f85800
board[1] = 0x7f98c8f85800
board[2] = 0x7f98c8f85800
board[3] = 0x7f98c8f85800
board[4] = 0x7f98c8f85800
```

こちらも instance id(memory address)が全て同じです。理由は、[ここ](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/copy.py#L201)と[ここ](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/copy.py#L128)を見ると分かります。

```py
def _deepcopy_list(x, memo, deepcopy=deepcopy):
    y = []
    memo[id(x)] = y
    append = y.append
    for a in x:
        append(deepcopy(a, memo))
    return y

d[list] = _deepcopy_list

def deepcopy(x, memo=None, _nil=[]):
    """Deep copy operation on arbitrary Python objects.
    See the module's __doc__ string for more info.
    """

    if memo is None:
        memo = {}

    d = id(x)
    y = memo.get(d, _nil)
    if y is not _nil:
        return y
           :
```

`_deepcopy_list()` 関数の `for a in x: append(deepcopy(a, memo))` において、`board[0]` 〜 `board[4]` の instance id(memory address)が全て同一ですので、memoize(メモ化)された `board[0]` の instance id が `board[1]` 〜 `board[4]` に割り当てられてしまう結果になります(実質的に shallow copy と同じ動作)。

以上を回避して、本来の意味での deepcopy を行なう方法ですが、`makeboard` 関数の実行時点で別個の instance を作成する様にします。

```py
>>> def makeboard(w, h):
>>>   return [[0]*w for _ in range(h)]

>>> board = makeboard(5, 5)
>>> board[2][2] = 1
>>> print(board)
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

>>> for i, b in enumerate(board):
>>>   print(f'board[{i}] = {hex(id(b))}')

board[0] = 0x7f8dcef49900
board[1] = 0x7f8dcef49940
board[2] = 0x7f8dcef49840
board[3] = 0x7f8dcef49800
board[4] = 0x7f8dcef45600
```

その他、numpy を使う方法があります。

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> board = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=int)
>>> board[2, 2] = 1
>>> board
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[obj for _ in range(n)]
```

と書いた場合同じ obj を参照する要素を n 個持つリストを生成します。

> _ = [0 for i in range(5)]
> board = [_ for i in range(5)]

これは

```
board = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] for i in range(5)]
```

ということであり、１つの [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] オブジェクトを参照する要素を5つ持つリストを生成してしまいます。

```
board = [[0 for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]
```

とすれば、同じ 0 を参照する要素を5つ持つ [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] オブジェクトを5回生成し、これを要素にしたリストを生成できます。

```
board = [[0] * 5 for _ in range(5)]
```

としても同じ 0 を参照する要素を5つ持つ [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] オブジェクトを5回生成し、これを要素にしたリストを生成できます。

なお、

```
board = [[0] * 5] * 5
```

とした場合は同じ 0 を参照する要素を5つ持つ [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] オブジェクトに対して、この１つの [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] を参照する要素を5つ持つリストを生成してしまいます。

python の変数やコンテナの要素はすべて参照変数であり参照要素です。
（リファレンスでは束縛と表現していますが他の言語の参照相当です。Java や C# の参照相当です。C++の参照とは違います。）
変数やコンテナの要素には、実体のオブジェクトへの参照情報が格納されていると考えると分かりやすいと思います。