# python（ver.3.9）で９ｘ９の2次元配列（リスト）を作って， そこに九九の表を格納し， 格納後，表示したいのですが妙な結果が得られます。

Tags: python

ソースコードは次の通りです。

```
mt = [[None]*9]*9
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(9):
        mt[i][j] = (i+1) * (j+1)
        print("%2d " % (mt[i][j]), end=" ")
    print()

print(mt) # why
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(9):
        print("%2d " % (mt[i][j]), end=" ")
    print()
```

実行結果はなぜか次のようになってしまいます。

```
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  
 2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  
 3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  
 4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  
 5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  
 6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  
 7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  
 8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  
 9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  
[[9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81]]
 9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  
 9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  
 9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  
 9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  
 9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  
 9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  
 9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  
 9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  
 9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81
```

原因が分からずに困っています。
よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: 参考: [Python3 でリスト内のリストの要素を一つだけ書き換えたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/71256/)

Comment: 次の投稿はあなたの質問の回答になりますか？ [Python3 でリスト内のリストの要素を一つだけ書き換えたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/71256/python3-%e3%81%a7%e3%83%aa%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e5%86%85%e3%81%ae%e3%83%aa%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%81%ae%e8%a6%81%e7%b4%a0%e3%82%92%e4%b8%80%e3%81%a4%e3%81%a0%e3%81%91%e6%9b%b8%e3%81%8d%e6%8f%9b%e3%81%88%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

Answer (score 2):

`mt = [[None]*9]*9` を
`mt = [[None] * 9 for i in range(9)]` に変えれば直ります。

ご質問の結果となるのは[多次元配列の罠](https://note.nkmk.me/python-list-initialize/)です。
リンク先が詳細を記述していますが、`[None]*9`というリストをその外側で9個コピーしているため、**内部リストの実体は同一**です。

そのため、`mt[i]`を書き換えるたびに`mt[0]`から`mt[8]`まで全ての実体が影響を受けて、例えば下記のコードのように1の段の配列(`mt[0]`のリスト)も書き換わってしまいます。

```
mt = [[None]*9]*9
#mt = [[None] * 9 for i in range(9)]
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(9):
        mt[i][j] = (i+1) * (j+1)
        print("%2d " % (mt[i][j]), end=" ")
    print("1の段の配列 = %s" % mt[0])
```

出力結果:

```
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  1の段の配列 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  1の段の配列 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
 3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  1の段の配列 = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27]
 4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  1の段の配列 = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36]
 5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  1の段の配列 = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]
 6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  1の段の配列 = [6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54]
 7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  1の段の配列 = [7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63]
 8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  1の段の配列 = [8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72]
 9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  1の段の配列 = [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81]
```