# clear するとコピーしていた変数も変わってしまう

Tags: python, python3

```
a = [1]
b = a
a.clear()
print(b)
```

結果

```
[]
```

どうしてでしょうか？
@ver.3.8.4

追記
[python リストの要素を消す際のclear関数の注意点と対策](https://it-for-pharma.com/python-%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E8%A6%81%E7%B4%A0%E3%82%92%E6%B6%88%E3%81%99%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AEclear%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AE%E6%B3%A8%E6%84%8F%E7%82%B9%E3%81%A8%E5%AF%BE%E7%AD%96)

こちらのサイトでそれらしきことに言及されていたのですが、同じことなのでしょうか？

Comment: 参考: [Python3 でリスト内のリストの要素を一つだけ書き換えたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/71256)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

変数 `a` に代入されたオブジェクトを, 変数 `b` に代入すると, 同じものが入ります
`id()` で比較すると同じオプジェクトであることが分かる

```py
>>> a = [1]
>>> id(a)
140486539736384
>>> b = a
>>> id(b)
140486539736384
```

コピーする場合は, 次のように行うと, 別のオブジェクトになる

```py
>>> b = a.copy()
>>> id(b)
140486539736192
>>> a.clear()
>>> b
[1]
```

コピーには, 浅い (shallow) コピー, 深い (deep) コピーなどもあります

参考: https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/copy.html

---

追記のサイトの記事は, だいたい似たようなことかな

---

##### 追記

説明が不十分な気がするので, 追記

```py
a = 3.141592
b = a
```

この場合も, 同じ数値オブジェクトが入ります。
けれど, ミュータブル / イミュータブル なオブジェクトで違いがあり
数値オブジェクトは書き換え不可なため, 次のような演算でも別のオブジェクトになります
なので, この場合 `b` は影響受けません

```py
a += 1
```

参考:

- (docs.python.org) [データモデル](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/datamodel.html)
- (docs.python.org) [なぜ list 'y' を変更すると list 'x' も変更されるのですか?](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB#why-did-changing-list-y-also-change-list-x)