# pythonの変数代入に関する質問

Tags: python, python3

質問なのですが，下記のようなプログラムをPython 3.8にて実行したら結果が空のリストになりました．なぜニトリという変数とイケアという変数が同じ変数のように扱われているのでしょうか．勉強不足でしたら申し訳ございません．

ちなみに下記以外の書き方にて回避したため，今後の勉強のため，回答お願いします．

```
nitori=[0,1,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ikea=nitori
del nitori[5:]
del ikea[:5]
print(nitori)#[]
print(ikea)#[]
```

Comment: この辺の記事を参考に。[copy --- 浅いコピーおよび深いコピー操作](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/copy.html), [\[Python\] リストの複製、浅いコピーと深いコピー](https://webbibouroku.com/Blog/Article/post-1558), [Python♪「参照渡し」「浅いコピー」「深いコピー」まずは理屈抜きで覚えよう。](https://snowtree-injune.com/2018/07/17/post-565/)

Comment: list typeのオブジェクトを作り出し `nitori`へ代入, `ikea`に `nitori`が指しているオブジェクトを代入。なので同じオブジェクトを指している。ということです。ちなみに [Python ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/)では, 束縛(bindings), 浅い (shallow) コピー, 深い (deep) コピー … の三種類です。答えが重複しそうなのでコメントで。[clear するとコピーしていた変数も変わってしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/80987/)